# How to deploy gem with related branch for different environments using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano 3 to deploy a RoR application. I already have deployment scripts for different environments: stage, production, etc.
But I need possibility to deploy on these environments with different gem branches. For example, if I will deploy to production I want to use gem's master branch; if I will deploy to stage I want to use gem's develop branch and etc.
I already have solution with custom branch definitions for each environment like this for production:

```
gem 'custom-gem', git: 'path-to-git', branch: 'master'
```

But I need more flexible solution in Capistrano way, not custom definitions for each branch. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your gem to groups like in Gemfile

```
group :staging do 
gem 'custom-gem', git: 'path-to-git', branch: 'stag'
end

group :production do 
gem 'custom-gem', git: 'path-to-git', branch: 'master'
end
```